# New HTML email rules: How to center without margin: auto?

Tags: css, html, email, html-email

As per new email rules (thanks Microsoft and Google) all margins are stripped from your HTML. So using `margin: 0 auto` is out for a solution.

The structure is:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="THIS IS THE ELEMENT I NEED CENTERED" style="display: block; width: 50%;">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Now I could add yet another table inside the `td` but it is already like the 2nd nested table and I'm hoping there is a different solution other then nesting another table. The `align="center"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code, I'm using this code to send html email and it works fine for gmail, outlook

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <a href="THIS IS THE ELEMENT I NEED CENTERED" style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, you can check allow css property for html email here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: You should also set `width="100%"` in table just to ensure maximum compatibility.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yNEjZE

Comment: it's just an example, the trick here is text-align and inline-block

Comment: Yes it seems this is working fine. I tried inline-block but with different combinations and this is the winning combo here. Thanks.

Comment: the inline block isn't necessary. you can technically achieve this with pure html and no css. Check my pen above.

Comment: your pen doesn't have display property, i think @o_O needs to set block display for button element

Comment: The display property is not necessary for the effect to be achieved. The button is centered. 

The display property would be related to the layout of the button in context to surrounding buttons. Because there are none, we shouldn't assume inline or block as it doesn't matter for this to be achieved. If he wanted to center three links inline or stacked (for example), then the display property would factor in. Til then, KISS

Answer (score 3):

Old, school, but why not just use blank td's on each side? Ah, it's the 90's again!

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%"></td>
    <td width="50%">
      <a href="THIS IS THE ELEMENT I NEED CENTERED" style="display: block; width: 100%;">Button</a>
    </td>
    <td width="25%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If we have <Button element> dynamicially (2, 3 or more), you will seperate more <td> tag I think :D

Answer (score 3):

Cuz CSS in email is dangerous... buh BAM. ;D

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <a href="THIS IS THE ELEMENT I NEED CENTERED">Button</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```